# Why byte array of .doc or .docx file in Java changes everytime the file is saved again in MS Word?

Tags: java, file, arrays, streamreader, doc

I am trying to read a .doc or .docx file in a byte Array in Java. I am not looking forward to use any third party APis like Apache POI, TIKA, doc4j, etc.
The code at its simplest level is:-

```
Path file_path = Paths.get("D:\\", "myname3.doc");
    byte[] ByteArray= Files.readAllBytes(file_path);
    for(byte b : ByteArray){
        System.out.print(b);
    }
```

Code is working fine and I receive the byte array. However, when I open the same file again in MS Word, makes no changes, but save it again in the same drive with same contents, the byte array that I receive is totally different. I understand that differences in MetaData pertaining to modified time exists, but the byte Array is totally different, as if the whole content of file has been changed. (attaching the text files containing byte Array of both the iterations).
[Difference in Byte Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDysi.png)

Is there a solution to this without using third party APIs?

Note:- I have gone through Word encoding format given at MS website, and also, looked at the endianness issues just in case. Also tried reading the file through FileInputStreamReader.

Note:- This program is working fine for Text files in ASCII format.

EDIT 1:- just to make the question lucid. When I read the .docx file which is saved twice at same location with dfferent name, the byte array is completely different when I read the file using the program above. I would like to know the reason behind this.

EDIT 2:- i tried reading the files in OffVis tool, there also, the raw bytes are different.

Comment: What is the question? Is not clear.

Comment: Try saving the two byte arrays again on the disk and see if the two files will open and if they have the same content

Comment: Since I'll have to convert byte array to char format, content won't be same since bytes are converted to char. @tfosra

Comment: No you don't have to save each byte as a char but rather use your byte array in a ByteArrayOutputStream to save all the data back to another physical file. You can also use the `Files.write(...)` method

Comment: Storing Byte array in byteArrayOutputStream and then writing it to another file is nothing but copying the bytes from one file to another. When I am receving a different byte array each time, contents of the array won't change if I copy them to another file.

Answer (score 1):

This can be definitely be explained for **.docx**,  which is simply a [zipped, XML-based file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML). Since it is a compressed file, a slight change in one of the underlying files can drastically change the bits of the archive file globally.

Not sure why it happens with doc.

Comment: I tried doing it for Doc file, but the byte arrays are different.

Answer (score 0):

.Doc file yields same byte array everytime.
.docx file, as stated in answer, is a zipped OOXML file, and hence, when I tried looking for binary through officeVis, some extra bytes were added and hence whole byte array was either shifted, or changed.
Another observation, there is a security application in my system which was encrypting .doc files, hence, when I tried reading file through my smartphone (which doesn't have security application), all worked fine.

Thanks for the help.